# input/output error when copy or link a file containing escape characters from home directory to a nfs system

Tags: ubuntu, mount, nfs, fstab

Suppose that I have a home directory `/home/mydir`,which has a file containing time format (YYYY-MM-DD_HH:MM:SS) in its filename. When I try to copy or link these files to a nfs directory, it will report an error, something like

```
cp: cannot stat './2013010206/NARR_3D:2013-01-03_00': Input/output error
cp: cannot stat './2013010206/NARR_3D:2013-01-03_03': Input/output error
cp: cannot stat './2013010206/met_em.d01.2013-01-02_12:00:00.nc': Input/output error
cp: cannot stat './2013010206/met_em.d01.2013-01-02_15:00:00.nc': Input/output error
```

or

```
$ cp ~/tests/2013010206/met_em.d03.2013-01-02_12\:00\:00.nc .
cp: cannot stat './met_em.d03.2013-01-02_12:00:00.nc': Input/output error
```

I think that it is related with the escape characters (backslash `\`) in the time format (`12\:00\:00`), since when I use this command

```
$ cp ~/tests/2013010206/met_em.d03.2013-01-02_12\:00\:00.nc met_em_2013-01-02_12
$ ls
met_em_2013-01-02_12
```

It is ok. So the problem is how to deal with it? Is there some setting in the NFS that I can modify, because this kind of time format file is needed for a lot of my running exe.

And the following is the setting in `/etc/fstab`

```
IP:/share1   /share1     nfs     rw,sync,nosuid,rsize=65536,wsize=65536    0 0
```

--update for mount options--

`rw,nosuid,relatime,sync,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=10.15.1.19,mountvers=3,mountport=2049,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=10.15.1.19`

Comment: I guess that your problem has to do with the share being exported by a windows machine -- you cannot use `:` in filenames in windows.

Comment: I'm not aware of any nfs option to mangle the file names so as to make them usable on non-unix systems (either for the server or the client).

Comment: Add to question to tell us what the mount options are? `findmnt -T .`

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, the option is `rw,nosuid,relatime,sync,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,naml`

Comment: @AllenZhang that's truncated -- `naml` probably stands for `namlen=...`. Try with `findmnt -uT`. Though that may be absolutely pointless -- AFAIK `nfs` does not mangle names and `mount -t nfs` does not have any option for that.

Comment: @mosvy, I want to use multiple nodes to do a `mpirun` task. So I tried to use `nfs`, where I put some `exe` in. But these `exe` need the input and will create output both containing the `:`. Other than modify the code (since it is a large system), is there any ways to satisfy the need.